# Disabled button after x seconds

Tags: javascript, angularjs

im working with angularjs and i have a button for create tickets and this work with http request, for call a php web, the problem is the http request have a delay of x seconds, and people can make so much clicks in this delay, the result, varius tickes create and only 1 work, them i need put a delay in the button, but i cant make this work, please check this and note the solution should be outside of `request` [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lt7aP/860/)

Comment: So what is the issue? You do or do not want the extra clicks to fire the Ajax calls? Why don't you just disable the button on click and enable it when the Ajax call is complete?

Comment: "i need put a delay in the button, but i cant make this work" seems to be the actual question here.

Comment: @jmar777: My understanding is that the issue is users spam multi-clicking the button and making multiple API calls while the login goes through, so the solution is to disable the button after the first click. I could be completely wrong though. We are understanding the question differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular provides a `$timeout` service component for this:

```
$timeout(function() {
    $scope.betDelay=false;
}, 1000);
```

Among other things, when you use the `$timeout` helper, it performs dirty model checking for you automatically (which by default won't happen when you use the default `window.setTimeout()`).

Basically, Angular isn't going to just keep checking non-stop whether or not `$scope` has changed; it only checks at key points in a component's lifecycle, and $timeout helps you tie into that lifecycle.

See the updated JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lt7aP/862/

---

As an alternative, you can also explicitly tell the `$scope` that it needs to perform dirty checking via `$apply()`.  E.g.,

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $scope.betDelay=false;
    $scope.$apply();
}, 1000);
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Lt7aP/863/

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of your post is that the user can hit the login button multiple times, making multiple duplicate entries (the API doesn't have time to check for existing records, because it's being hit so fast).

We handle this by checking if the button was already clicked. Make a variable called `$scope.isButtonClicked` and set it to false. Check if it's false onClick. If it IS false, set it to true and make your request.

```
  function LoginController($scope) {
    $scope.isButtonClicked = false; 
    $scope.login = function () {
        if($scope.isButtonClicked === false){
            $scope.isButtonClicked = true
             var request = $http({
                        dataType: 'json',
                        method: "post",
                        url: "/xxx.php",
                        data: {
                            data1: $scope.data1,
                            data2: $scope.data2
                        },
                        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
                    });
            request.success(function (data) {       
                /* note i try puting a delay in the top, but idk why this cant work */
            });
        }  
    };
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/obohxukw/2/